# How do I make calls I dial from my mobile phone go through Google Voice?

Tags: mobile-phone, google-voice

I know I can dial the the Google Voice web interface, but obviously I'm not always near my computer when I want to call someone. Is there a way to make any call I dial go out with my Google Voice number? This primary benefit of this is that people who receive my calls would see my Google Voice number displayed, rather than my mobile number.

Note: I saw [this](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/10/use-google-voice-with-your-existing.html) today, but I'd like to do it without losing functionality. I just have a regular mobile phone, not a smartphone.

[Follow-up concerning SMS](https://superuser.com/questions/62222/how-do-i-make-texts-i-send-from-my-mobile-phone-go-through-google-voice)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Voice, which is a webapp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call your google voice number from your phone (if its registered) and it will ask for your pin number then give you the option (option #2 at this time) to make an outgoing call. There is also a way to modify your phone book entry so these steps are automated, here is an article worded for modifying a contact on the iPhone on how to do it but it should work with any mobile that allows you to save phone numbers (pretty much any phone).

[Make a call through GV](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2009/08/12/make-calls-through-google-voice-from-your-iphone-contacts)

Answer (score 2):

> Call-backs: Unlike text messages, Google Voice doesn't provide a magic call-back number to avoid re-introducing your "old"/carrier number to contacts. If Voice's mobile or desktop web sites are accessible, you have to call into your Google Voice number, hit 2 to place a call, then enter the number you're calling back. That's a pain in the rear, and even more so if you don't feel comfortable setting your cell phone to not require a PIN when you call Google Voice.
>
> If you're calling certain contacts all the time and want the calls to go through Google Voice, you could search to see how to insert one- or two-second pauses into a phone number in your phone's address book. Then create an "Other" number for them that consists of your Google Voice number, then a pause, then "2," then a pause, then that contact's actual phone number, followed by a "#". That automates the Google Voice dialing, leaving you with just a bit of a wait while it goes through.

[How to Ease Your Transition to Google Voice via Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5311254/how-to-ease-your-transition-to-google-voice)